# Populate Drop Down List Box with values from array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, list, drop-down-menu

I have a requirement to populate a drop down list box in my form with human races. I believe I've done it correctly but I get an error that says **Error: Unable to get property 'appendChild' of undefined or null reference**

What am I doing wrong?

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html />
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="TheCSS.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1 {
            height: 26px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\JavaScript     Projects\TheJavaScript.js"></script>
    <center>
        <table class="style1">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <center>
                        <h1><b>New Hire Form</b></h1>
                    </center>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="subHeader" colspan="4"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style3">First Name</td>
                <td class="style2">
                    <input type="text" id="FirstName" onchange="return LastName_onchange()" />
                </td>
                <td class="style4">Last Name</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="LastName" type="text" onchange="return FirstName_onchange()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style1">Sex</td>
                <td class="style1">Male
                    <input id="Radio1" checked="true" name="R1" type="radio" value="M" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Female
                    <input id="Radio1" checked="true" name="R1" type="radio" value="F" />
                </td>
                <td class="style1">Race</td>
                <td class="style1">
                    <select id="RaceDropDown" name="D1"></select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style3">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="style2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="style4">
                    <input type="button" id="myButt" value="Submit Entry" onclick="return      myButt_onclick()" />
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var select = document.getElementById('RaceDropDown');
var options = ["Asian", "Black"];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}

function LastName_onchange() {
    var LastName = document.getElementById('LastName').value;
    var FirstName = document.getElementById('FirstName').value;
    document.getElementById('subHeader').textContent = FirstName + " " + LastName + " " + new Date();
}

function FirstName_onchange() {
    var LastName = document.getElementById('LastName').value;
    var FirstName = document.getElementById('FirstName').value;
    document.getElementById('subHeader').textContent = FirstName + " " + LastName + " " + new Date();
}
```

**CSS:**

```
#subHeader
{
    text-align: right;   
}
```

Comment: seems to work fine mate ([**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/eH5bC/)). When is the script being called? As a side, `i<options.length` is enough because the array Index starts with 0.

Comment: I'm calling the script in the body of the HTML.

Comment: Is it after the code for the element `RaceDropDown` or before it?

Comment: I'm calling it before it.

Comment: The script should be called after the element is created, else it would not be able to find the element when it is being executed. can you move this script to just before the `</body>` tag?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35638/discussion-between-mwilson-and-harry)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
for (i = 0; i <= options.length; i++)
```

to

```
for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
```

Just need to do `<` . not `<=`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comments, the script should be called after the element is created. If not, the script would throw an error because it will not find the `select` element to add `options`.

Please create a function for populating the drop-down and call it `onload` like the below:

```
function popDropDown() {
    var select = document.getElementById('RaceDropDown');
    var options = ["Asian", "Black", "White"];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var opt = options[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
}

window.onload = popDropDown;
```

As an aside, in the for loop `i < options.length` is enough instead of `i <= options.length`.